# RxJs Observables in Angular 1.x usage optimization

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

I'm creating an Angular 1.6 application with RxJs to extend my services, but I have te feeling that one of the things I created could be written better.

So my list function get's a filter object that get's updated via an other service, or a subject in the services itself. Therefore I'm combining them and subscribing to that.

but then I want to update a public Observable after the list is called. But doing a `.subscribe()` followed by a `.next()`  feels weird. Is there any other way of doing this?

the code that does this looks like this:

```
constructor(private $log: ILogService,
            private $q: IQService,
            private http: Http,
            private appConfig: AppConfig,
            private searchService: SearchService) {
  this.pagingSubject = new Subject<Page>();
  this.applicableMachinesSubject = new Subject<ApplicableMachineFilterResponse>(); // Will store all incoming http requests
  this.applicableMachine$ = Observable.from(this.applicableMachinesSubject);

  Observable
    .combineLatest(this.searchService.searchTermsHash$.throttleTime(250), this.pagingSubject)
    .share()
    .subscribe((next) => {
      // If less then 1 subscriber don't continue
      if (this.applicableMachinesSubject.observers.length < 1) {
        return;
      }
      const filter: ApplicableMachineFilter = assign(new ApplicableMachineFilter, next[0], next[1]);
      this.list(filter)
          .subscribe((f) => {
            this.applicableMachinesSubject.next(f);
          });
    });
}

private list(filter?: ApplicableMachineFilter): Observable<ApplicableMachineFilterResponse> {
  const validFilter: ApplicableMachineFilter = this.validate(filter);
  return this.http
             .get(`${this.appConfig.api}/ApplicableMachines`, {params: validFilter})
             .map((res) => (res as any).data);
}
```

we rewrote the $http service of angular 1 to work with Observables